# Create a generic ViewModelFactory in WPF/CaliburnMicro/AutoFac

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, autofac, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application using Caliburn.Micro and AutoFac

In the Bootstrapper.Configure() I register my Views & ViewModels as :

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    //  register view models
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblySource.Instance.ToArray())
        .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
        .AsSelf()
        .InstancePerDependency();
    //  register views
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblySource.Instance.ToArray())
        .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("View"))
        .AsSelf()
        .InstancePerDependency();

    builder.Register<IWindowManager>(c => new WindowManager()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    _container = builder.Build();
}

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
{
    return new[]
    {
        typeof (MainViewModel).Assembly, // assembly that holds all the ViewModels
        typeof (MainView).Assembly // assembly that holds all the Views
    };
}
```

This works nice, the views and viewmodels are nicely mapped by this convention, eg. when instantiating a RandomViewModel, the RandomView is shown.

Furthermore, I have a lot of edit/list viewmodels that derive from generic base classes, where the generic types are the entities in my solution.

For instance, when I have entities UserEntity, OrderEntity, AccountEntity, etc... 
Then I would create classes:

```
//base classes
abstract class EditViewModelBase<T> : IEditViewModelBase where T: IEntity
abstract class ListViewModelBase<T> : IListViewModelBase where T: IEntity

//implementations
class UserEditViewModel : EditViewModelBase<UserEntity> {...}
class OrderEditViewModel : EditViewModelBase<OrderEntity> {...}
class AccountEditViewModel : EditViewModelBase<AccountEntity> {...}
...
class UserListViewModel : ListViewModelBase<UserEntity> {...}
class OrderListViewModel : ListViewModelBase<OrderEntity> {...}
class UserListViewModel : ListViewModelBase<UserEntity> {...}
...
```

Now I want to create a ViewModelFactory to locate viewmodels in a generic way:

```
class ViewModelFactory
{
    public IEditViewModelBase CreateEditViewModel<T>()
    {
        //this method should do :
        // if typeof(T) == typeof(UserEntity) return new UserEditViewModel();
        // if typeof(T) == typeof(OrderEntity) return new OrderEditViewModel();
        // if typeof(T) == typeof(UserEntity) return new UserEditViewModel();
        ...
    }

    public IListViewModelBase CreateListViewModel<T>()
    {
        //this method should do :
        // if typeof(T) == typeof(OrderEntity) return new OrderListViewModel();
        ...
    }
}
```

How would I solve this so I don't have to change the ViewModelFactory everytime I add a new Entity & ViewModels to my solution ? 
I was thinking about looping over the container, using reflection tricks like IsInstanceOf and Activator.CreateInstance, but I can't get it to work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is by using the [Auto Factory](https://github.com/thepirat000/AutoFactory) library that internally uses AutoFac. 
You can resolve it like this:

```
using AutoFactory;
class ViewModelFactory
{
    private IAutoFactory<IEditViewModelBase> _editFactory = Factory.Create<IEditViewModelBase>();
    private IAutoFactory<IListViewModelBase> _listFactory = Factory.Create<IListViewModelBase>();

    public IEditViewModelBase CreateEditViewModel<T>()
    {
        return _editFactory.SeekPart(t => t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name == typeof(T).Name);
    }

    public IListViewModelBase CreateListViewModel<T>()
    {
        return _listFactory.SeekPart(t => t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name == typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to do it directly with AutoFac, you can do for example:

```
using Autofac.Builder;
using Autofac.Features.Metadata
class ViewModelFactory
{
    private IContainer _container;
    private IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<IEditViewModelBase>>> _editParts;

    public ViewModelFactory()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(this.GetType().Assembly)
           .Where(t => typeof(IEditViewModelBase).IsAssignableFrom(t))
           .As<IEditViewModelBase>()
           .WithMetadata("type", t => t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
        _container = builder.Build();
        _editParts = _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<IEditViewModelBase>>>>();
    }

    public IEditViewModelBase CreateEditViewModel<T>()
    {
        return _editParts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Metadata["type"] as Type == typeof(T)).Value.Value;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I struggled a bit with it, becuase apparently the factory class needs to be declared in the same assembly as the ViewModels. I did it first in my main executable, next to the bootstrappers because I didn't want the Autofac references in my ViewModels assembly ... but I moved the factory to my ViewModels project now and it works as a charm. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Note you can also pass the viewmodel assembly as a parameter to the AutoFactory `Factory.Create` method or to the AutoFac `Builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes`

Comment: Yup, i just noticed it and am moving it back to my executable assembly :) I did see that my ViewModels are now being reused ..everytime I do a CreateViewModel I get back the same instance, which is not so good because I have an MDI application and I need separate instances eg. for editing 2 userentities in different tabs

Answer (score 0):

I tink

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
  public IContainer Bootstrap()
  {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>().As<IEventAggregator>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<MessageDialogService>().As<IMessageDialogService>();

    builder.RegisterType<FileDataService>().As<IDataService>();
    builder.RegisterType<fLookupProvider>().As<ILookupProvider<f>>();
    builder.RegisterType<fGroupLookupProvider>().As<ILookupProvider<fGroup>>();
    builder.RegisterType<fDataProvider>().As<IfDataProvider>();

    builder.RegisterType<fEditViewModel>().As<IfEditViewModel>();
    builder.RegisterType<NavigationViewModel>().As<INavigationViewModel>();
    builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf();

    return builder.Build();
  }
}
```